# GA4 Event - Pardot form Submission Thank You Code

Tags: analytics, pardot, google-analytics

I'm looking for an Example to submit a GA4 event on Pardot Form submission Thank You Code.
Does anyone have an example for me which can be used from within Pardot Thank you code.

Whats the javascript event for inserting a custom event in GA4

Thanks!